# $A\subseteq B\iff B^c\subseteq A^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove without using Venn diagram that $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $B^c\subseteq A^c$?

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265360/a-subseteq-b-if-and-only-if-b-subseteq-a

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $A \subset  B$. Let $ x \in B^c$. Then $x \not\in B$. Then $x \not \in A$. Thus $x \in A^c$.

Similarly assuming that $B^c \subset A^c$. Let $x \in A$. Then $x \not \in A^c$. Thus $x \not \in B^c$. Hence $x \in B$

Answer (score 1):

This is elementary logic. Assume that $p \in B^c$ *and* $p \in A$. Then, by assumption, $p \in B$, a contradiction. Hence $B^c \subset A^c$. To conclude, just reverse the argument.

As you see, everything reduces to the properties of logical negation.